# SQLite3::SQLException error

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I created an entity scaffold using

**rails g scaffold entity entity:string genre:string url:string **

I had already created it before but i destroyed it before recreating it again using the above command

However when I run rake:db:migrate I keep getting the error;

```
SQLite3::SQLException: table "entities" already exists: CREATE TABLE "entities" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "entity" varchar(255), "genre" varchar(255), "url" varchar(255), "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime) /home/notebook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
```

Can somebody help me point out what is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using destroy scaffold does not run the rollback to the migration. The correct way of doing it would have been

`rake db:rollback
 rails destroy scaffold level`

now, as you don't have that other migration anymore, you cannot roll it back. You'll need to delete that table manually:

`rails dbconsole
 DROP TABLE levels;`

This should solve your problem